# snwochange error while running an sql statement

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using python connector to deploy a sql create table script to snowflake using snowchange and my arguments are passed correctly in CLI.
Not sure why but I receive this error while running the command. because the variables are properly declared.

sql script:

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {{ db_raw }}.schemaname.TEST1  (
TABLENAME VARCHAR(100),
SOURCE_SYS VARCHAR(100),
SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100)
);
my script looks something like below.

pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python

python $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/snowchange/snowchange/cli.py -a $(SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT_NAME) -u $(SNOWFLAKE_DEVOPS_USERNAME) -r $(SNOWFLAKE_ROLENAME) -w $(SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE) -c TST_ENT_RAW.SNOWCHANGE.CHANGE_HISTORY --vars '{"DB_CURATED": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_CURATED)", "DB_RAW": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_RAW)", "db_curated": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_CURATED)", "db_raw": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_RAW)"}' -v -ac

error:

usage:
2021-07-06T12:24 snowchange: error: argument --vars: invalid loads value: "'{DB_RAW:"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have both uppercase and lowercase var names listed. ("DB_RAW" and "db_raw") Your script seems to refer to db_raw. JSON is case sensitive. Have you tried removing "DB_RAW"?

--vars '{"DB_CURATED": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_CURATED)", "db_curated": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_CURATED)", "db_raw": "$(SNOWFLAKE_DB_RAW)"}'

Comment: No, this doesnt seem to be issue ..because I have both db_raw and DB_RAW variables and values declared in variable groups. However I have tried your way still the issue is same with inavalid loads value error